# The conversion of the varchar value overflowed an int column ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource, sqlexception

I have a `SqlDataSource` in ASP.NET that is returning an error

> unhandled System.Data.SqlClient.SQLException, The conversion of the varchar value '5157964168' overflowed an int column

I am not sure why it is complaining about an int column as nothing in my code is an int column. What should I look for?

```
protected void SqlDataSourceA_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
 e.Command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = DropDownListID.SelectedValue;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SqlDataSourceA.SelectCommand = "SELECT ID, FolderName FROM DR_Folders where parentID=CONVERT(BIGINT,@ID) AND parentID!=0 order by FolderName ASC";
}

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceA" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="">
        <SelectParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="ID" DbType="String" />           
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Stepping through I see 5157964168 in `DropDownListID.SelectedValue`.  I don't understand why it doesn't go into `@ID` and execute properly.  Isn't `@ID` a string?

I've also tried `Type="String"` instead of `DbType` because I'm not sure of the difference.

Comment: looks like ID is an INT to me.  What does your DB definition say?

Comment: You're converting @ID to a BIGINT

Comment: My column ID and parentID are BIGINT.  @ID however is not.  It should be a string or varchar in SQL world and be converted to BIGINT.  The number above is valid for BIGINT.

Comment: while I don't think this is the case for this situation, sometimes there is a trigger that is sending data to a table with an int column

Answer (score 2):

Rather than converting @ID to a BIGINT convert parentID to a VARCHAR instead:

```
SqlDataSourceA.SelectCommand = "SELECT ID, FolderName FROM DR_Folders where CONVERT(VARCHAR, parentID)=@ID AND parentID!=0 order by FolderName ASC";
```

Though comparing INTs to VARCHAR is probably asking for trouble whatever approach you take.

Comment: I can't see how that error would occur with the change suggested. Are you sure this is being executed? Have you put a breakpoint in to make sure?

Comment: Yes, I checked.  It is set.  I get the feeling that this is happening after the SQL calls.  Is it possible since these SQLDataSources are Bound to DropDownLists that the error is actually then?  I took notice I now get about a new value 5162322298 even though tracing through I still see the old value 5157964168

Comment: Running in SQL I get the same message doing either `SELECT ID, FolderName FROM DR_Folders where CONVERT(VARCHAR, parentID)=5157964168 AND parentID!=0 order by FolderName ASC` or `SELECT ID, FolderName FROM DR_Folders where CONVERT(VARCHAR, parentID)='5157964168' AND parentID!=0 order by FolderName ASC` Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The conversion of the varchar value '5157964168' overflowed an int column.  It changes to 5162322298 if I don't use single quotes around the ID

Comment: I even made my columns VARCHAR in the database and am still getting the same error.

Comment: I suspect the query you've given may be a red herring. Another poster mentioned triggers. I'd have a look and see a trigger is getting fired somewhere. Also if you have anymore details paste them into your OP, any info will make it easier to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The SqlParameter class allows you to define the SqlDataType when creating them as shown in this constructor reference on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f14f0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This can also be set after the fact as shown in this MSDN article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.dbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here is an example of how you could update your code to ensure it is set:

```
protected void SqlDataSourceA_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
 e.Command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = DropDownListID.SelectedValue; // May need parsing to Int64 here
 e.Command.Parameters["@ID"].DbType = DbType.Int64;
}
```

By explicitly setting the parameter to BIGINT, you don't have to do a convert in your SQL, so your command would be as follows:

```
  SqlDataSourceA.SelectCommand = "SELECT ID, FolderName FROM DR_Folders where parentID=@ID AND parentID!=0 order by FolderName ASC";
```

Comment: If passing a BigInt to the query isn't an option, you may want to try "CAST(@ID as BIGINT)" instead of "CONVERT(BIGINT,@ID)" and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried both the above way and removing the CONVERT as well as the CAST you wrote in comment.  Same error from both.  Removing the parameter all together works, of course returning the wrong data.

Comment: Have you tried running SQL Trace to see the statement that is actually being sent so that you can then run it in SQL Management Studio to debug it? This is all based upon the SQL Server tools being installed on your system. It might be easier to resolve by isolating it in that fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the error to go away by changing the database columns from BIGINT to VARCHAR and changing the SQL to

```
SqlDataSourceA.SelectCommand = "SELECT ID, FolderName FROM DR_Folders where parentID=@ID AND parentID!='0' order by FolderName ASC";
```

While this doesn't really answer why I had all the problems with BIGINT perhaps it is better that they are text the whole way through.